# SQL Query Finding a common id in a column based on unique elements in another column

Tags: mysql, database

I've been struggling to try to find a relatively simple way to perform this query. I have tried joins and wheres, and even tried to perform the logic outside of the query, but it gets very complicated.

This is my SQL:

```
AttributeName_Id     |     ProductPrice_Id
    9                    |     1
    4                    |     1
    9                    |     2
    5                    |     2
    9                    |     3
    6                    |     3
    9                    |     4
    7                    |     4
```

I have inputs 9 and 5. How would I perform a query so I can retrieve the value 2?

Comment: Could you post your query statement as well?

Comment: What are 9 and 5 and how do they evaluate to 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`, because it is very flexible:

```
select ProductPrice_Id
from table t
where AttributeName_Id in (9, 5)
group by ProductPrice_Id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that the table has no duplicates; otherwise, you might want `count(distinct)`.