# SQL Query Sets Within Sets Query with Exact Matching

Tags: sql

I want to select a Product_Id based on an array of Attribute_Ids, based on an **EXACT** match. For example, if I queried Attribute_Ids of 9, 4, and 2, I would want the query to return the Product_Id of 1. However, if I queried 9 and 4, I would NOT want anything returned. How would I do this?

```
Attribute_Id             |     Product_Id
    9                    |     1
    4                    |     1
    2                    |     1
    9                    |     2
    5                    |     2
    9                    |     3
    6                    |     3
    9                    |     4
    7                    |     4
```

Right now, I am able to return a fuzzy match based on a previous question. How would you modify this to get an EXACT match?
[SQL Query Finding a common id in a column based on unique elements in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819191/sql-query-finding-a-common-id-in-a-column-based-on-unique-elements-in-another-co)

```
select Product_Id
from table t
where Attribute_Id in (9, 5)
group by Product_Id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product_Id
FROM table 
GROUP BY Product_Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Attribute_Id IN (9, 5) THEN Attribute_Id END) = 2 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Attribute_Id NOT IN (9, 5) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The above query returns those `Product_Id` values related to *both* `Attribute_Id` values 9 and 5 **and** not related to any other `Attribute_Id` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3ab3/2)

Comment: Before I try this out, if I gave it just an Attribute Id of 9, and nothing else, I should expect nothing returned (based on the example table in my question), am I correct?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, this is correct. The second predicate of the `HAVING` clause would filter all `Product_Id`s out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Question: The THEN 1 part in the query flags all the rows where the condition following CASE WHEN is true. Where does the 1 go? Is it just appended as a new column at the end of the table?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause doesn't return anything. So the `1` value is just used to check for existence or not existence of records that belong to the same `Product_Id` group and are related to `(9,5)`.

Comment: So this means that I could put anything after THEN keyword? Like THEN this_row_selected END? Or is the 1 a special value (similar to true)?

Comment: @Andrew Any `NOT NULL` value after `THEN` is OK, but `1` makes the code more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Got it. Just for others, I tried the code out, but it doesn't work with DISTINCT, but it works without the DISTINCT keyword. I think it's because the result of the first HAVING condition would always return 1 (and never equal 2 or any other number) with DISTINCT?

Comment: @Andrew My bad, it should be `THEN Attribute_Id` instead of `THEN 1` inside the `CASE` expression. `DISTINCT` is only necessary in case there are duplicates. i.e. multiple occurrences of 9 or 5.